# Styles in Singleton Widgets: H1 and H2 not being saved

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Ways to reproduce the problem:

add a simple Singleton widget, like this:

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'textBlock', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
    toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic' ],
    styles: [
      { name: 'Title', element: 'h3' },
      { name: 'Hero Title', element: 'h1' },
      { name: 'Another Title', element: 'h2' }
    ]
}) }}
```

Change the styling of the text-block, refresh the page and observe that only the h3 style is saved on the fly, as it should be. H1 and H2 styles are applied but not saved.

Could be that I am running Apostrophe on Windows or that I am using mongod with **--smallfiles**?

The project files are available at: https://github.com/newdesignideas/veebidisainer-koduleht.git

Comment: Edit: fixed another error myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know I'm the architect of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

This is a simple one: you're running into our HTML filtering. This is a great feature because it prevents pastes of dodgy markup and inline CSS from Word and similar programs from wrecking your responsive design. But, sometimes you want to allow a different set of tags than we do. We typically reserve H1 and H2 for "template-level" stuff like the title, but you can change that.

Just check out the [configuring CKEditor in Apostrophe](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/ckeditor.html) HOWTO, which covers, among other things, how to configure sanitize-html so that different tags are allowed — in your case by adding H1 and H2.

So please, don't blame Windows or the smallfiles flag. (:

Comment: Thanks Tom, is there a way we can donate or show appreciation for your great support?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for asking! We just made the donation button live in the top navigation of:

http://apostrophecms.org

In addition, check out enterprise support: http://apostrophecms.org/support/enterprise-support.html

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom, just donated. We are currently bootstrapping an app so money is tight - but I think every tiny gesture counts :) 

My personal take on making Apostrophe profitable is to offer it as a service.

Something like Squarespace - but with the angle that is more tuned to custom designer made templates. Promoting the ease of in-context editing for the end-user and ease of using nunjucks to develop one's own templates.